# Why did my file-system suddenly become corrupted and why can I not repair it?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, filesystem, boot-repair

A few months ago I built a computer to host my Minecraft server on, it ran great for months on end, but a few weeks ago it decided overnight to corrupt my file-system. I woke up to find that the drive was read-only and upon restarting it took me to GRUB Rescue and told me I had an unknown file-system. I left it for a few weeks since I haven't had time, but now I decided to finally get around to doing it. I read a bunch of websites recommending using Boot Repair, fsck, etc but nothing worked. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm happy to provide more information if necessary and I have a Boot Repair paste-bin thing that seems to indicate I don't have an OS anymore? If possible I really really want to get the drive back intact, but I'm not sure exactly how to accomplish that.

Thanks!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ssrjc7XQZ6

EDIT:

- I have an SSD installed.
- When I first realized it was in read-only (before I restarted and got to GRUB Rescue) I tried putting in an external drive but it was unable to mount.
- I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Would guess you had a power outage/surge during the night.  Would use USB to see if any files readable.  Add version of Ubuntu you are using so someone can help better.

Comment: Sounds like part of the drive or file system has been damaged.  Would run Smart data from USB to check drive.  Is drive hard drive or SSD?

Comment: I'm using an SSD on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm trying to figure out how to edit that into the main message. I also tried inserting an external hard drive I have when I first realized what had happened and it couldn't mount I believe was the word. As for a power surge it's possible but I don't think so, the main thing I want to do is get the files off the computer, I don't care about salvaging the OS or programs, I can just reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for corrupted data :

- Improper voltage on component, this may be voluntary (overclocking, not connecting the machine to an Uninterruptible Power Supply) or involuntary (defect in Uninterruptible Power Supply, Power Supply, voltage regulators elsewhere).
- Improper shutdown.
- Storage got above maximum temperature allowed by manufacturer.
- Writing to raw device.
- Bad sectors.
- Malicious software or script due to human or software security flaw.

You could try to repair the file system using the [tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/en/man8/fsck.8.html) associated to said file system you chosen after making a full image backup of the drive.

If you do not have a favorite imaging tool yet, you may want to check [ddrescue](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ddrescue.1.html) and [dd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/en/man1/dd.1posix.html) man pages.
ddrescue may not be pre installed, use `sudo apt install gddrescue ddrescueview` to install it.

You can execute it from a livecd's terminal, including the installation part in case the livecd does not come with this tool pre-installed.

Comment: Thanks! How would I make a full image backup though? When Ubuntu was still functional I tried using fsck and some other commands (I don't remember which but I can try to find out) and they didn't work.

Comment: Boot from ubuntu install media, like you would to do a new install. Backup can be made using your favorite tool (visibly none), ddrescue is a good start if you don't know where to go http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ddrescue.1.html

Comment: So would I install it from the terminal and run it through the Try Ubuntu option? (And sorry for asking so many questions, I'm a fairly adept Windows user but know next to nothing about Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, you would install it using a terminal from the "try ubuntu before you install it" if ubuntu iso does not come with it already ready for you.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I'll see if I can give it a go right now.

Comment: A couple quick questions sorry.
1. Can I safely plug a backed up USB into my Windows computer or will it do some overriding or not function between OS's?
2. Will ddrescue tell me how much space the backup will be? And what will happen if I don't have enough space on the USB?

Comment: The backup will be the exact same size as the drive is. If your drive is 500Gb, the image will be 500Gb. Note that it does not mean data is recoverable, it just allows you to keep whatever is potentially recoverable somewhere else as we cannot trust your drive.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll probably be back with more questions about recovery once I figure out how to back up (sorry!).

Comment: Search or open new questions where possible.

Comment: Will do! Didn't find anything for this question.

Comment: Should not mix OSs, use Windows for Windows and Linux for Linux.  Windows can't see/read Linux files/OS.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea if they use universal file types or something (I only had the one OS installed).